# Splitting data in R - simple by rows

Tags: r, dataframe, split

All, I have what is likely a very simple question in R, but I'm having trouble sorting out a few issues with the existing answers pertaining to this problem.

I want to split my dataset in two, so that I can use the predict() function.  My dataset is 27 rows, not including headers.  I only want to split it into a 20 row and 7 row set (two sets).  When I use the `split` function, not only can I only figure out how to split into groups that are multiples of the total number of rows, but the resulting object changes the variable/header names, prefacing each with `X1.`.

The current code that I've tried and like is,

`data=newdata
indexes = sample(1:nrow(newdata), size=0.8*nrow(newdata))
test = data[indexes,]
train = data[-indexes,]`

But this results in a random grouping of rows, not the first approximately 20.  How can I get a result that returns the first 20 and last 7?  Apologies for the simple question, any insight is very much appreciated!

Comment: If you want to select specific columns, the general code would be `data[rows,columns]`

So you would do `test = data[1:20]` to select rows 1 to 20, and `train = data[21:27]` to select rows 21 to 27.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to separate the first twenty rows from the remaining rows:

```
first_twenty <- newdata[1:20 , ]
last_seven <- newdata[21:nrow(newdata), ]
```